# ZIO.fail not fail

Tags: scala, zio

I want learn methods refineXXX of zio library.
For this purpose I write simple code

```scala
import zio.ZIOAppDefault
import zio.Unsafe.unsafe
import zio._

import java.sql.SQLException

object Bot extends ZIOAppDefault {

  val codeWithExc: ZIO[Any,Throwable,Int] =
    ZIO.fail(new SQLException("message of SQL error."))

  val MainApp: ZIO[Any, Throwable, Int] = for {
    _ <- Console.printLine("Begin")
    res <- codeWithExc
    _ <- Console.printLine(s" res = $res")
  } yield res

  def run: URIO[ZIOAppArgs, ExitCode] =
    for {
      res <- MainApp.exitCode
    } yield res

}

unsafe { implicit u =>
  Runtime.default.unsafe.run(Bot.run.provide(ZIOAppArgs.empty))
}
```

When I run it in IDEA worksheet I see output:

```
Begin
res0: zio.Exit[Nothing,zio.ExitCode] = Success(ExitCode(1))
```

and expect fail in res <- codeWithExc and death of the main fiber.

Comment: When I add foldZIO like this 
res <- codeWithExc.foldZIO(
        err => Console.printLine(s"Error = [${err.getMessage}]-[${err.getCause}]").as(0),
        suc => ZIO.succeed(suc)
    )
Then I see message: Error = [message of SQL error.]-[null]

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that You are mapping ZIO to `.exitCode` which returns `URIO` that cannot really fail. Failure will be mapped to success and the only reason to tell that it did actually fail is to verify that `ExitCode` was not `0`. If You change Your code and replace that with something like below, it will look work correctly:

```
 def run = MainApp
```